# Populate django table column across multiple levels of foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I need to populate a column of my table with an property from a model separated from the table model by multiple levels of foreign keys. When I attempt to access the property, I just get a dash for every row instead of the value of the property.

From tables.py:

```
class AssignmentsTable(tables.Table):
    ...
    full_name = tables.Column(accessor='assignment.participant.full_name', verbose_name='First & Last Name (Participant)')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = AssignmentDetail
        sequence = (..., "full_name", ...)
```

From models.py:

```
class AssignmentDetail(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
    ...

class Assignment(models.Model):
    ...
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Is this something that can be done with django tables, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work like you showed.

I just checked in the django-tables2 example: [table](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/6e49205f54a8e1d60a947c4b2ee1472c466b05e7/example/app/tables.py#L28), [models](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/6e49205f54a8e1d60a947c4b2ee1472c466b05e7/example/app/models.py#L10).

[image: Screenshot of column spanning multiple relations]

I am not sure what prevents your example from functioning properly though...

Comment: Good to know. I guess I'll have to try and get the site running in a more debugging-friendly environment and keep looking.

Comment: Turns out it actually is working. The participant field was deprecated at some point in favor of something else in the models, but was never removed or documented as such. As a result, every Assignment has the field, but it's entirely unpopulated.